# Parts-of-speech tagging and finding relevant phrases in documents

Tags: corpora, parts-of-speech

I've got a corpus of half a million text documents. I'd like to identify phrases in each document that are the most descriptive with which to build tag clouds. Let's say that I identify the most frequently occurring unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams in each document and apply TF/IDF or some other algorithm that ranks phrases more highly if they occur frequently in one document but not very frequently in the entire corpus. That will give me a set of candidate phrases but, in my experience, that approach gives me a fair number of phrases that are not really meaningful.

So, I'm wondering what strategies I might want to consider that include considering parts of speech.

The site http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/demo_view/pos has a demo of parts-of-speech tagging. If I use their demo text and click "submit" I get this as the first paragraph:

> NNPS/Helicopters MD/will NN/patrol DT/the  JJ/temporary JJ/no-fly
>   NN/zone  IN/around NNP/New NNP/Jersey POS/'s NNP/MetLife NNP/Stadium
>   NNP/Sunday , /, IN/with NNP/F-16s VBN/based IN/in NNP/Atlantic
>   NNP/City JJ/ready TO/to  VB/be VBN/scrambled IN/if DT/an
>   JJ/unauthorized NN/aircraft VBZ/does VB/ enter DT/the VBN/restricted
>   NN/airspace ./.

If I pull out nouns, optionally preceded by adjectives, I get these phrases:

```
Helicopters
patrol (not a noun in this context but I'm just blindly pulling out phrases as a piece of code would)
no-fly zone
New Jersey
MetLife Stadium Sunday
F-16s
unauthorized aircraft
airspace
```

This is not a bad start but I'm wondering how I could tighten up the algorithm? And, I'd love references to research on this approach to relevant phrase extraction.

Comment: If you're just looking for common phrases I have a phrase project I spent several months on. It is based on the ANC spoken corpus. Is that half a million words or documents? If you don't mind me asking, what kind of corpus are you using?

Comment: @bmende It's half a million scientific documents.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of documents. 
You might want to add another tag to your question, perhaps something like "corpora."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[ If I understand, you ideally want all meaningful phrases even where the head is not a noun, eg "save the day", "ready for action", "fantastically" or "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious". ]*

You must break down the problem.

**0. Sentence Segmentation and Tokenisation**
I'm assuming this is already done.

**1. Find named entities**
You need a first pass to find entities. (So `New Jersey` is basically represented as `New_Jersey` and has nothing to do with `Jersey`.)  This is different than `unauthorized aircraft` (which does have something to do with aircraft).

**2. Canonical forms**
Use a lemmatiser like [spaCy](https://spacy.io) to turn `helicopters` into `helicopter-n` and `is dancing` into `dance-v`.
(You could do stemming to get `fantasy` or `fantastic` from `fantastically`, but this is often too aggressive.)

**3. Improve the selection algorithm**
Allow overlapping windows.  If the set of tags for a document includes `UK immigration`, it should also include `UK` and `Immigration`.

**4. Synonymisation**
This is almost the opposite of canonicalisation.  If the set of tags for a document includes `UK`, it should also include `United Kingdom`, and vice versa.

You will need to experiment to determine the optimal behaviour and order of the steps for your application.

And each of the steps introduces some risk: improve x% of cases but with false positives that corrupt y% of cases.